# One event for several forms

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, events

I am currently faced with a trivial task but I can't think of a solution.

In order to explain the theory of how it should work ...

There is a form of authentication. http://prntscr.com/pwat5

This form fits on `TabControl` -> `TabItem` and `TabControl` in turn is placed on the component `Grid`.
Actually, on that key input is an event by clicking authenticate and change the login form to another form.

Such forms of authentication, I need more, I went for it in the following way and laid the form data to a specific component, the structure looks like this:

```
Grid
 ListBoxItem
  MyAuthForm
   ... //Well, actually imposed on the rest of the crap form MyAuthForm
```

For an identical copy of my form `MyAuthForm` I clone the object, and to be more precise, I clone `ListBoxItem` together with all its contents to the new object and thus add it to the component Grid, that is, get a new cloned object.

```
Grid
 ListBoxItem
  MyAuthForm
   ... //Well, actually imposed on the rest of the crap form 
 ListBoxItemСlone
  MyAuthFormСlone
   ... //And so on
```

But the problem is that my original object carries a variety of events but the cloned object can not deliver on certain events in the original.

How is it possible to solve this problem? To clone an object somehow could refer to the events of the original object?

In general, explained as best I could, I hope most accessible outlined what I want, thank you very much for any hints and ideas, the second day I suffer with this case and so far no ideas.

**ps** In the manual for each cloned object, I can not create events for such forms of authentication can be more than enough, everything has to be fast, so the only option is to somehow refer to already existing events, wpf allowed for that possibility?

Comment: I have to admit that I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve and what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps since you are working with WPF, if you bind the events to commands or any other mechanism then the cloned window, given the same datacontext would target the same methods and your problem would be solved.

I hope i understood correctly.

In the past i used Caliburn with WPF and there was something called [ActionMessage](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/07/17/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-pt-3-all-about-actions.aspx) there that might be of use to you.

It bubbles up through datacontexts until it finds a method with the specified name or else it throws an exception. Maybe you can use this, coupled with the fact that the 2 clones share the datacontext instance to enable you to make them all point to the same authentication method.

Hope i got it right.

Comment: if possible, can you give more examples?

Comment: i'm not sure what is the context of your code so that's why i explained as general as possible. All you basically need to do is modify the existing code to use ActionMessages to call the method you want when the events are fired and when creating a clone you must set it's datacontext to be the datacontext of the instance you are cloning (if that is not done automatically by cloning) and it should work